# windows 11 installation - product title problem

Tags: windows-11

I am installing the following version:

en-us_windows_11_consumer_editions_updated_jan_2022_x64_dvd_39009ccb.iso

over the current version:

Microsoft Windows 11 IoT Enterprise Insider Preview

At some point this window pops up:

[image]

My question is: Why does it say "Install Windows 11 IoT Enterprise".

That's not the one I am installing.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Where did you downloaded the installation tool?

Comment: My Visual Studio Essentials subscription.

Comment: "Why does it say `Install Windows 11 IoT Enterprise`" - What were you expecting it to say?  You are downgrading from an Insider Preview build to a the stable version of Windows 11 as of January 2022 (21H2). "That's not the one I am installing." - Actually that is the version you are installing.  In addition to not being able to downgrade to an earlier build you can't change which edition of Windows you have installed except in the case of an upgrade (Home to Professional) using the method you are using to install Windows 11.

Comment: All I want is to reformat my HD and have a fresh installation. Is it not possible to do when the installation starts within the existing system?

Comment: create bootable installation media from that iso, boot from it and do a clean install.

Comment: Still, I dont understand how using media for consumer version I will get the same version as my current system installed.

Comment: @Mark - The ISO you are installing as several editions installed on it.  SInce you currently have Enterprise IoT that is the edition that will be installed.

Comment: Another words, I cannot downgrade my version?